# Join all nested arrays of a collection in one array in mongodb c#

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb

I have documents with this structure:

```
    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a26f1764cacd91bf4624a76"), 
        "CompetitorIds" : [
            "3a11f1764cacd91bf4624b84",
            "2a26f1764cacd91bf4624a55"
        ],
        "BusinessId" : "5a1bfcac2b8fb6096885cbb8"
    }
```

And I want to get an unique array with all competitorIds, for example, if I have these documents:

```
    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a26f1764cacd91bf4624a76"), 
        "CompetitorIds" : [
            "111111111111111111111111",
            "222222222222222222222222"
        ], 
        "BusinessId" : "5a1bfcac2b8fb6096885cbb8"
    }
    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("7a26f1764cacd91bf4112a88"), 
        "CompetitorIds" : [
            "333333333333333333333333",
            "444444444444444444444444"
        ], 
        "BusinessId" : "5a1bfcac2b8fb6096885cbb8"
    }
```

I want an array like:

```
["111111111111111111111111","222222222222222222222222","333333333333333333333333","444444444444444444444444"]
```

Now, I'm doing like this, using MongoDB.Driver to C#:

```
public class Product
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string[] CompetitorIds { get; set; }
    public string BusinessId { get; set; }
}

public List<string> GetAllCompetitors(string businessId)
{            
    var builder = Builders<Product>.Filter;
    var filter = builder.Eq(p => p.BusinessId, businessId) & builder.Where(p => p.CompetitorIds.Length > 0);
    var collection = _collection.Find(filter);
    var productIdsAlreadyBound = collection.ToList().SelectMany(x => x.CompetitorIds).ToList();
}
```

But I want to know if there is a better way to do that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `var productIdsAlreadyBound = _collection.Distinct("competitorIds", filter);` or  `FieldDefinition<Product> field = "CompetitorIds ";
var productIdsAlreadyBound = _collection.Distinct(field, filter);`

Comment: @Veeram It didn't work

Comment: Be sure to remove the trailing space from "CompetitorIds " in the example that @Veeram provided. Also, you may need to use the lowercase version here because that's what your sample data contained before I changed that in order to be in line with your C# representation.

Comment: Working and tested version. Assuming upper case for field names. Using FieldDefinition `FieldDefinition<Product, string> field = "CompetitorIds";             IList<string> productIdsAlreadyBound = _collection.Distinct<string>(field, filter).ToList<string>();` or Using string field name `IList<string> productIdsAlreadyBound = _collection.Distinct<string>("CompetitorIds", filter).ToList<string>();`

Comment: Worked! I just had to change the property to lower case: `FieldDefinition<Product, string> field = "competitorIds"; IList<string> productIdsAlreadyBound = _collection.Distinct<string>(field, filter).ToList<string>();`

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** While the below works @Veeram's solution in the comment up there is way more elegant.

Here is how you can do that:

First, you define a type that represents your document structure after the (required) `$unwind` stage. This type just makes the C# client nicer to deal with so you can write typed code instead of fiddling with `string`s.

```
public class ProductAfterUnwind
{
    public string CompetitorIds { get; set; }
}
```

And then you can do this:

```
var productIdsAlreadyBound = _collection
    .Aggregate()
    .Match(p => p.BusinessId == "5a1bfcac2b8fb6096885cbb8")
    .Unwind<Product, ProductAfterUnwind>(p => p.CompetitorIds)
    .Group(p => string.Empty, grouping => new
    {
        CompetitorIds = grouping.Select(p => p.CompetitorIds).Distinct()
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: That's - see my comment above - very likely related to your data which uses lowercase "competitorIds" whereas - without any additional mapping - my code assumes uppercase versions.